# Sublime Text 3 package key binding conflict with CTRL-d and CTRL-l

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-3

I see lots of questions about *finding* key binding conflicts in Sublime Text 3, but not how to fix them. I followed the guidance [here](https://superuser.com/questions/528905/sublime-text-conflicted-shortcuts/528909#528909) to copy the package's default key binding file to the package's user key binding file and replaced the conflicted key binding (here `CTRL-d` and `CTRL-l`) with non-conflicted key bindings (here `CTRL-SHIFT-d` and `CTRL-SHIFT-l`). But when I use `CTRL-d` or `CTRL-l` in the file-type for the conflicted package (Stata's .do files) I get the conflicted key binding action (i.e., *not* select word or line). This is even after restarting Sublime Text 3.

Is there a way to fix this conflict? Or even turn off all key bindings for a package?

FWIW, the package is [`StataEditor`](https://github.com/mattiasnordin/StataEditor) and here is the changed portion of the `StataEditor` user key binding file.

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+d"],   "command": "stata_execute", "args": {"Mode": "do"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.stata" }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "stata_execute", "args": {"Mode": "run"}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.stata" }
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I believe you can solve the problem temporarily is to install the package PackageResourceViewer which is available from Package Control. You can then edit the StataEditor default file. However, the drawback is that this change I believe will be overridden when StataEditor is updated. Another way is to change the user settings as you have done above, but also include the default use of ctrl + d and ctrl + l.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+l"], "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "line"} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+d"], "command": "find_under_expand" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+d"], "command": "find_under_expand_skip" },
```

You can read more on the issue here (though the SO link might not be valid for ST3):

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13303
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245837/how-to-unbind-a-key-binding-in-sublime-text-2

As the author of the package, I will agree that ctrl + l was a poorly chosen shortcut. I mainly did it for my own convenience at the time, but I might change it with another update. I will most likely let ctrl + d remain as I want to make the transition smooth for Stata users who are accustomed to the default editor.

Comment: Hey, Mattias! Thanks for the help (and a great package)! The first link doesn't solve the question (I had tried that option, but failed to include it in my post). But the second link *does* solve the question. And I don't think the `PackageResourceViewer` is required, I could just navigate to the default key bindings file using the menus. Thanks for the help -- I just be less averse to editing the default files. :)

Comment: Just for clarification: Did you edit the default file founded at Preferences -> Package Settings -> StataEditor -> Key Bindings - Default? If so, a word of caution is in order as those changes will be overwritten whenever the package is updated.

Comment: Yes, I edited the default key bindings file via `PackageResourceViewer` and understand that this file will change when you next update the package (that was my hesitation in editing in this file). I guess it will be obvious when this happens. :) And the CTRL-l and CTRL-d hot keys are logical, I'm just a former Vim user and miss the ability to quickly select lines and words. Thanks!